# How to give input for scanner class in reflection method for dynamic code execution

Tags: java, reflection

I was doing a project which is a web compiler and I am using reflection method for code execution. but I am not able to pass any value for scanner class in order to read from the java program. how can I pass a value for scanner class using method of reflection api

```
  String paramsObj[] = {"hellooo"};
  File f = new File("/location/to/class");
  URL[] cp = {f.toURI().toURL()};
  URLClassLoader urlcl = new URLClassLoader(cp);
  Class clazz = urlcl.loadClass(filename.trim());
  Object iClass = clazz.newInstance();
  Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };
  String[] mainArgs ={"Abcd","defg"};
  Method thisMethod = clazz.getMethod("main",argTypes);
  thisMethod.invoke(null,(Object)mainArgs);
```

this is how i am calling main method , can anyone please help me to solve this ...?

Comment: Side note: you are going to have ludicrous security problems doing anything like this.

Comment: then what should i do , can you suggest some way

Comment: Not for this project, frankly.

Comment: @user8177026 if you create a custom security manager you can mitigate some security issues at the cost of reducing functionality that the code you are running can do. I would still strongly recommend against this strategy because of the security implications.

Comment: security risks i understood . if i am running the code inside a container , wiil that work ?